# GL Blending on light color Cocos2dx

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using `CCBlade` in my game from [here](https://github.com/ChipmunkCommunityCN/RockChipmunk2D/tree/master/Classes/FruitCutNinja)  which creates a blade effect on swipe, it works great on black screen. But I got a problem when I tried to use it in lighter color screen, my game has **light blue sky color**. I think there is something to do with the **`blending`** which `CCBlade` using. It is currently using

```
GL::blendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

**What could be the correct combination?** So that the blade effect is visible on light color. See the image below for more clarification

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although i have not that much experience with blending myself, i m using [this](http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php) great online tool for my current project to find suitable blend options according to my needs, don't be shy to experiment a bit, also some theory to crunch [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Blender)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have already checked this, tried lots of combinations. Not able to get the right one.

Comment: i am not sure but if u could give it a try like GL::blendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);